# Vuejs, unable to serve project

Tags: vue.js, npm, serve

I installed a vuejs package, tho' it gave me errors so I removed it and I am still unable to serve my project.

Log:

[image: error log]

Comment: try to remove node_modules and run `npm install` again ?

Comment: Based on the error message it looks like it is splitting the file path at the `&` symbol. Have you ever been able to run `npm run serve` from inside this directory?

Comment: @0x5453 Yes, I have bene running it from the project directory where package.json is located and worked for over a month. Btw if I delete node_models will I have to install router and vuetify again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have this `"@vue/cli-service": "~4.2.0",` in your dependencies in `package.json` and delete node_modules folder and run `npm install` again